# Is this way of creating detached std::thread with pointer to instance wrong?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I've come across classes whose only function is to continuously do some work in a loop and they are designed such that they define a public method that can be called to invoke this member function in a new `std::thread`. I'm referring to something like this:

```
class ThreadLooper {
 public:
  ThreadLooper(const std::string &thread_name)
      : thread_name_{thread_name}, loopCounter_{0} {}

  ~ThreadLooper() {
    cout << thread_name_ << ": destroyed and counter is " << loopCounter_
         << std::endl;
  }

  void run() {
    std::thread([this]() { detachedThreadLoop(); }).detach();
  }

 private:
  void detachedThreadLoop() {
    cout << thread_name_ << ": detachedThreadLoop() started running"
         << std::endl;
    while (true) {
      using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
      ++loopCounter_;
      cout << thread_name_ << ": counter is " << loopCounter_ << std::endl;
    }
  }

  std::string thread_name_;
  std::atomic_uint64_t loopCounter_;
};

int main() {
  cout << "In main()" << std::endl;
  {
    ThreadLooper threadLooper{"looper1"};
    threadLooper.run();
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(20s);
    cout << "main() done sleeping, exiting block scope..." << std::endl;
  }

  while (true) {
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(20s);
    cout << "main() woke up..." << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It seems like because the function running in the detached thread has a pointer to the instance but can continue to run beyond the lifetime of that instance this is bad. I've seen other classes where the thread isn't detached and then in the destructor a flag is set to tell the thread loop to exit and the thread is then joined in the destructor. It seems like the latter is the correct way to do this and that the former relies on the fact that the class will only be used in situations where instances of it live for the duration of the program. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Threads have little to do with the core issue, and you seem to already understand that. The problem is one of the automatic scope of an object terminating, and with that the object itself, leaving any references or pointers to said-same "dangling". Any dereference thereafter invokes UB. The same problem frequently happens without threads by returning a reference or pointer to an automatic from a simple function call, then utilizing it afterward. I.e. `Type x, *p = &x; return p;` in some `Type *foo()`. Calling that function, then exercising the result after the object it long gone, invokes UB.

Comment: If you post this as an answer I'll accept it. The involvement of the implicit `this` here is why I wasn't as sure as with the other examples you provided.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using `std::thread::detach` means you need to have your own method of making sure the thread terminates before all the resources it uses are destroyed.

In this case `ThreadLooper` will invoke undefined behaviour when the program exits the first block scope in `main()`. It's better to not use `detach()` then `std::thread` will call `std::terminate` if you've forgotten to call `join()` before the thread (and its containing object) are destroyed.

Comment: You don't need to "detach" a thread in order for it to use a dangling pointer. You can still make that same mistake in a thread that wants to be `join()ed`.  You just have to work a little harder at making it is all.